# Tab item appears unclear in ajax:TabPanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using `<ajax:TabContainer>` & `<ajax:TabPanel>` but some how I cannot see tabs clearly. It just half of the tab.

Here is my code :

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>

  <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>

 <ajax:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1">
            <ajax:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tbpnluser">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Home
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <b>Registration Form</b>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                UserName:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtuser" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Password:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtpwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password"> </asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </ajax:TabPanel>
 </ajax:TabContainer>
```

Output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpRnS.jpg

I have changed AJAX dlls all that but not getting anything.... Anyone has any idea???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put the rendered HTML into the jsfiddle?

Comment: change your active tab index to 0, you have only 1 tab and index always starts from 0